# Синхронизация фукнций с condition_variable C++

Tags: многопоточность, c++11, concurrency, condition-variable

Есть два потока. В 1-ом работает бесконечный цикл, в котором постоянно вызывается функция `f1()`. Во втором потоке достаточно редко вызывается функция `f2()`. Одновременная работа `f1()` и `f2()` не допускается. Необходимо чтобы при вызове `f2()` работа первого потока приостанавливалась (так скоро, как это возможно) и `f2()` отрабатывала без простоя процессорного времени. То есть использовать `mutex` в чистом виде не желательно.

Пример с `mutex` (нежелательная реализация):

```
mutex mtx;

void f1() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mtx);
    // some work
}

void f2() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mtx);
    // some work
}
```

Думал об использование `condition_variable`:

```
mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;

void f1() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mtx);
    // some work
    cv.notify_one();
}

void f2() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
    cv.wait(lk);
    // some work
}
```

В данном случае функция `f2()` начинает работу после использования `cv.notify_one()`. При этом `cv.wait(lk)` усыпляет поток, что позволяет не тратить процессорное время.

Проблема: Если функция `f2()` вызывается до начала работы первого потока, то её выполнение не начнется до первого вызова функции `f1()` и срабатывания `cv.notify_one()`. Как сделать так чтобы `f2()` могла начать работу до вызова `f1()`? Может использование `condition_variable` здесь не уместно? Как тогда реализовать подобную идею ?

Comment: Дык может тебе внутри реализаций этих функций использовать atomic-и?

Comment: А чем, по-вашему, использование `condition_variable` поможет? Можно привести пример последовательности выполнения кода в потоках, который должен отличаться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас функция `f2` вызывается намного реже функции `f1`, то думаю, вы можете реализовать [spin-блокировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) с помощью [std::atomic_flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void f1() 
{
    while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
}

void f2() 
{
    while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
}
```

Функция [`test_and_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set) пытается установить значений атомарного флага в true. Если атомарный флаг уже установлен в 1, то цикл ожидания "захвата" флага продолжиться, и будет выполняться spin-операция. Иначе флаг захватит текущий поток. В качестве spin операции в данном примере используем операцию засыпания  потока на 1 миллисекунду.  Цикл будем крутиться до тех пор, пока флаг не будет сброшен при помощи функции [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/clear) из другой функции.

Comment: Спасибо. А есть ли возможность после вызова функции `f2()`, прервать бесконечный цикл в котором выполняется `f1()`? То есть каким-либо образом уведомить первый поток о том, что `f2()` была выполнена и выполнение `f1()` больше невозможно.

Comment: В конце выполнения f2 у вас вызывается функция clear для атомарного флага, соответственно в функции f1 функция test_and_set начнет возвращать false, и бесконечный цикл в f1 "незамедлительно" прервется.

Comment: Наверное, не правильно выразился. Работа вашего примера мне понятна, но вопрос в другом. Есть некий **внешний** цикл в котором постоянно вызывается `f1()` (всё это работает в первом потоке). Тут начинает работу второй поток и вызывает функцию `f2()`. Есть ли возможность прервать **внешний цикл** в первом потоке и больше не выполнять `f1()`,  после единожды вызванной функции `f2()`. Другими словами: `f1()` должна вызываться в бесконечном цикле в первом потоке, но только до момента вызова `f2()`. После вызова `f2()` бесконечный **внешний** цикл необходимо прервать.

Comment: А чем мешает завести volatile булевскую переменную, и выставлять признак вызова f2 в функции f2? Во внешнем цикле анализировать значение данной переменной. В f1 также после spin цикла можно проверять данный флаг на необходимость выполнения данной функции